# Where is Simba DB SQL Reference?

Tags: sql, syntax

I have never used Simba DB before... however my boss needs me to do integration between Simba DB and our system.

I just want to see the syntax of Simba SQL. However I can get no result on internet.

I just want to know two syntax.

One.  Type conversion statement

`select convert(StartDate, varchar)) from MyTable`

where StartDate is `Date` type. I want to convert to char or varchar. But I got

`System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [Simba][SimbaEngine ODBC Driver]The second parameter varchar for CONVERT is invalid.`

Two.  Inner sql statement

`select * from (select * from MyTable)`

This syntax is totally failed.

Please help...orz...

Alex

Comment: i don't think Simba specifies a specific SQL syntax. i believe developers use Simba to build ODBC/JDBC drivers, and they get to shape the flavor of SQL it accepts. i'm using Simba to access an old IEX/TotalView database, and it seems to prefer a variety of [DB2 syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rbhelp/v6r3/topic/com.ibm.redbrick.doc6.3/ciacg/ciacg25.htm#sii02desc703036) for `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation here: http://www.simba.com/odbc-sdk-documents.htm

Comment: Could you kindly tell me which file I can find the `convert` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well...
Got following examples from a Simba contact:

```
select convert(DATE_COL1, SQL_VARCHAR) from Date
select convert('2011-04-01', SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP)
select convert('2011-04-01', SQL_TYPE_DATE)
```

Which i could apply successfully!